# If $x^2+ky^2$ represents $a$ and $ab$ must it also represent $b$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, quadratic-forms, representations-by-quadratic-forms

Consider the binary quadratic form $f(x,y) = x^2 + k y^2$ over the integers.

If there exists integers $u,v$ such that $f(u,v) = a$, we say that the form can represent $a$.

I can show that if $f$ represents $a$ and $b$ that it must also represent $ab$.

Is it possible to partially invert this and show that if $f$ represents $a$ and $ab$ it must also represent $b$?

If not, what are some necessary conditions which would allow this conclusions to go through? Maybe some restriction on the class number $h(-4k)$? I may have misunderstood, but I saw a lecture that seemed to assume this is obvious when the class number is odd. I'm hoping there is a simple reason it is true in general, but am having trouble proving anything.

---

My attempt

First note:
$$
\begin{aligned}
(r^2 + k s^2) (t^2 + k u^2) 
&= (r t)^2 + (k s u)^2 + k((s t)^2 + (r u)^2) \\
&= (r t + k s u)^2 - 2k r u s t + k (s t - r u)^2 + k 2 r u s t \\
&= (rt+ksu)^2 + k (st-ru)^2 \\
\end{aligned}
$$

Therefore if $f$ represents $a$ and $b$ that it must also represent $ab$.

Now focusing on whether representation of $a$ and $ab$ implies representation of $b$, I'll start with some given representation of $a$ and $ab$ and try to construct a representation of $b$.
$$
\begin{aligned}
a &= r^2 + k s^2 \\
ab &= x^2 + k y^2 \\
\end{aligned}
$$
Then using the identity above, try to solve for $t,u$ from
$$
\begin{aligned}
x &= (rt+ksu) \\
y &= (st-ru) \\
\end{aligned}
$$
as this would give $t^2 + k u^2 = b$.

Combining the equations we find:
$$
\begin{aligned}
sx - ry &= u (k s^2 + r^2) = u a \\
rx + ksy &= t (r^2 + k s^2) = t a \\
\end{aligned}
$$
​We will get the desired conclusion if we can show
$$
\begin{aligned}
sx - ry &= 0 \pmod{a} \\
rx + ksy &= 0 \pmod{a} \\
\end{aligned}
$$
​so that our solutions for $t$ and $u$ are integers.

I'm stuck here, and not sure if this is even the appropriate path to try to prove this.

Comment: $5$ is not represented by $x^2+25y^2$ but $25$ and $125= 5^2+25.2^2$ are.

Comment: @reuns Thanks, so we at least know it is not true in general. In that case $h(-4k)=h(-100)=2$. Do you think this might still be possible for cases when $h(-4k)$ is odd?

Comment: It seems that the sequence of $k > 3$ which satisfies this property is $5,6,10,13,21,22,30,33,37,42,\dots$. They are square free and congruent to $1, 2$ mod $4$. The sequence is not in OEIS.

Comment: @Whats $k$ satisfying which property? The property about $h(-4k)$ being odd? The property about $a$ and $ab$ being represented implying $b$ being represented? For what it's worth, $x^2+7y^2=8$ has the solution $(x,y)=(1,1)$, and $x^2+7y^2=16$ has the solution $x,y)=(3,1)$, but $x^2+7y^2=2$ has no solution in integers.

Comment: @GerryMyerson The latter, i.e. if $a, ab$ are both representable, then $b$ is representable. Thus your example means that $k = 7$ is not in that sequence. I didn't mention above that $k = 1, 2, 3$ are all **in** that sequence, but I excluded them by starting from $k > 3$ because the corresponding quadratic orders are special.

Comment: @Whats thanks. It seems the "square free and congruent 1, 2 modulo 4" condition is necessary but not sufficient, as $14$ satisfies those conditions but isn't in your list. So, how do you prove that the numbers you've listed satisfy the representability property, and that the ones you've left out don't? I think the proofs would be worth posting as an answer.

Comment: @GerryMyerson The reason that I said "it seems that" is exactly because I don't have a proof... In fact, from experimental results, I draw the conclusion that counterexamples all appear very early, if they exist. Thus I simply test all numbers up to $10^4$ and if no counterexample appears, then I put this $k$ in the list. My feeling is that the answer lies somewhere in the book "Primes of the form $x^2 + ny^2$" by Cox, but I forget most of these and cannot think clearly now.

Comment: @Whats OK, so, you've only tested $k$ up to $42$?

Comment: Also the condition "square free and congruent 1, 2 modulo 4" is equivalent to saying that $\mathcal O = \Bbb Z[\sqrt{-k}]$ is the maximal order of $K = \Bbb Q[\sqrt{-k}]$. And the problem can of course be stated as: when does $N_{K/\Bbb Q}(\mathcal O)$ equal $N_{K/\Bbb Q}(K)\cap \Bbb Z$?

Comment: @GerryMyerson I tested $k$ up to $100$. This list is all numbers up to $50$, if I remember correctly.

Comment: @WhatsUp I made some mis-steps, but I think I finally proved the conditions you found from numerical experiments. If you have a moment, can you check my math?

Comment: One may take $f$ any principal binary quadratic form, e.g. $x^2+xy+ky^2$, thus of discriminant $D=1-4k$. I find from experiment that, if $f$ represents $a$ and $ab$, some form $g$ of discriminant $D$ in the same genus as $f$ represents $b$. If each genus has 1 class, $f$ is reverse-multiplicative and represents $b$. If each genus has 2 or more classes (i.e. there are 2 or more principal classes), there are examples where $g$ represents $b$ but $f$ doesn't; e.g. $D=-28, -44, -23, -39$. It's not the total number of classes but whether there are 2 or more principal classes.

Answer (score 5):

Inspired by the conditions @WhatsUp found experimentally, I can now prove they are necessary.

That is:
If $k>1$ then it must be square free, and for $k \ge 4$ it must be 1 or 2 mod 4.

Note: These conditions are not sufficient, as noted by the $k=14$ case tested by WhatsUp.

---

### Step 1. Proving that $k>1$ cannot be a square.

If $k=n^2 > 1$, then
$f(0,1) = k$
$f(n,1) = 2k$
but $f$ cannot represent 2 since it is less than $k$ and not a square.
So to have this property, if $k>1$ it cannot be a square.

### Step 2. Proving that $k>1$ must be square free.

If $k=an^2$ with $a,n>1$ and $a$ is square free, then
$f(0,1) = an^2$
$f(n,0) = n^2$
but $f$ cannot represent $a$ because it is less than $k$ and not a square.

So combined with the previous step we can conclude that for the quadratic form to have this property, if $k>1$ it must be square free.

### Step 3. Proving the $\pmod 4$ conditions.

If $k=4n$ then it is not square free, and so if $k>1$ and $k \equiv 0 \pmod 4$ the quadratic form will not have the desired property.

For $k=4n+3$ it is helpful to split into a case analysis of when $(n+1)$ is a square or not.

If $k=4n+3$ with $n>0$ and $(n+1)$ not a square, then
$f(1,1) = 1 + k = 4(n+1)$
$f(2,0) = 4$
but $f$ cannot represent $(n+1)$ because it is less than $k$ and not a square.

If $k=4n+3$ with $n>0$ and $(n+1)=m^2$, then
$k = 4(m^2-1)+3 = 4m^2 - 1 = (2m+1)(2m-1)$
$f(2m + 1, 1) = (2m+1)^2 + (2m+1)(2m-1) = (2m+1)(4m)$
$f(2m - 1, 1) = (2m-1)^2 + (2m+1)(2m-1) = (2m-1)(4m)$
$f(2,0) = 4$

As $(2m+1)m$ and $(2m-1)m$ are less than $k$, they must both be squares to be representable. Since $\gcd(2m+1,m)=1$, and similarly $\gcd(2m-1,m)=1$, this also requires $2m+1$, $2m-1$, and $m$ to all be squares for these values to be representable. However there are no integer squares that differ by 2, so this is impossible.

All together this allows us to conclude that for the quadratic form to have the desired property, if $k \ge 4$ then $k$ must be 1 or 2 mod 4.

---

### Other Notes

I don't quite see what is going on yet, but the "bad" values of k seem to be related to almost all values that can be taken by a similar "form" of quadratic forms.

$$k = m^2 n - r^2$$

The main part that doesn't look nice in this is that the $n=1$ case seems to limit $r \in \{0,1\}$.

Consider $k = m^2$ with $m>1$
We've already shown these values of $k$ do not work.

Consider $k = m^2 - 1 > 4$
I couldn't find a quick example, but using previous work:
If $m$ is even, then $m^2 = 4t$, so $k = m^2 - 1 = 4(t-1) + 3$.
If $m$ is odd, then $m^2 = 4t + 1$, so $k = m^2 -1 = 4t + 0$.
So these $k$ will not work.

This appear to be the limit of general arguments against the difference of squares, as WhatsUp tests found that $k = 3^2 - 2^2 = 5$ was probably okay.

Consider $k = m^2n - 1$ with $m,n > 1$ and $n$ square-free
$f(1,1) = m^2n$
$f(m,0) = m^2$
cannot represent $n$, so this value of $k$ will no work.

More generally,
$k = m^2 n - r^2$ with $m>1$, $k>n>1$, and $n$ square free
$f(r,1) = m^2 n$
$f(m,0) = m^2$
Cannot represent $n$, so this value of $k$ will not work.
Unlike the $n=1$ case, here the values of $r$ are much less restricted.

Since another quadratic form seems to be rearing its head, there is probably something simpler connecting all this. Hopefully someone else can see the thread I am missing, and unravel the rest.

Comment: +1 I verified that your proof of the necessary condition is correct. I didn't think deep in this problem, but I can see that some more advanced results are involved here: [Hasse-Minkowski](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasse%E2%80%93Minkowski_theorem) says that a rational number is a norm of $N_{K/\Bbb Q}(K)$ if and only it is locally a norm for every place; In the book *primes of the form $x^2 + ny^2$* there is a result characterizing primes representable by this form; and this again is related to class field theory...

Comment: ...  I think by using these results, some further necessary or sufficient conditions can be proved, but I didn't get a complete answer and just gave up. Also I don't know whether this is a well-known problem (and the more general version asking when does $\Bbb Z \cap N_{K/\Bbb Q}(K) = N_{K/\Bbb Q}(\mathcal O_K)$ hold). Perhaps one could try mathoverflow if no expert answers here.